# How do I disable global menu for Libreoffice 4.0 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: libreoffice, globalmenu

I'd like to disable global menu for Libreoffice 4.0 in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. The global menu for the others applications had already been disabled after removing `appmenu-gtk3`, `appmenu-gtk` or `appmenu-qt`.

Comment: removing `lo-menubar` can help.

Comment: the lo-menubar aren't installed. this version of libreoffice 4.0 was installed by ppa:li­bre­of­fice/ppa and already come with global menu integration for unity

Answer (score 0):

The global menubar integration comes with `libreoffic-gnome`.

Comment: Not sure in 12.10, I did not use it, but in 13.04 the menu is handled by libreoffice-gtk and apparently removing that works, only the app looks really ugly! Another method is to use Alt-F10 to access (open) the menu.

Comment: The strange thing is that on machine I upgraded to 13.04 (and where I disabled global menus before) Libreoffice doesn't have global menus, but on a freshly installed 13.04 machine I still have the global menu after removing the `appmenu` packages. When I try to remove `libreoffice-gtk` I get a warning about a dependency conflict...

Comment: Ah, it turns out that I also needed to remove the `indicator-appmenu` package. Now both LibreOffice and Thunderbird) have regular menus.